# How can I prepare a Jetpack compose app to release, what about the @Preview composables?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

The source code of my Jetpack compose app is loaded with @Preview composables.

I prepared my app for release by removing all these @Preview composables from the source code, as we do, for example, with the log methods.

Is there any way to automate this removal process? More, is it really necessary to remove the @Preview composables from the source code?

Thanks,

Comment: R8 is gonna remove them right  because we are not calling that composable anywhere

Comment: You should surely use R8.

Comment: What if a not so clever developer accidentally calls the preview from production code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use ProGuard it will remove the preview composables as they are not used in your code base.

Comment: So, ProGuard will automate the removal process and I do not have to manually delete the Preview composables from my source code. Do I have to do any configuration in Proguard for that to happen?

Comment: The default configuration will remove them, they are not used so they get stripped.

Comment: What if you hold a reference in the preview to objects, collections, primitives etc in the same file or different package? My assumption is that anything referenced in the Preview will be excluded, as long as it is not used in a non-Preview Compose function as well.