# Preventing preview composables getting into release

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**What is the recommended safety measure to prevent `@Preview` composables from reaching release?** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69185826/how-can-i-prepare-a-jetpack-compose-app-to-release-what-about-the-preview-comp) question answered by using proguard but what if:

1. I'm not using proguard
2. I (accidentally) call the preview composable from the real code (proguard would not strip it due to the call reference)

Can / should I move the preview into `/debug` sources? Are there other safety mechanisms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark Preview functions with annotation `@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.TESTS)` so no one could use your function even within the actual code. The same you could do with the Preview-data variables to prevent access in production code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

One of the thing you can do is make your preview composable as a private function.

So, now you will have two functions, one is the actual composable, which you can use in your codebase. And, one is the preview composable, which will be private.

By keeping this preview as private, no one can be able to access your Preview composable, this way you can prevent the misuse.

Also, since there is no one referring to this private function, proguard can mark this function as `unused` and remove it.

Comment: If I define the preview as private I can still call it from within the same file. I could still call it from the actual code :( I would generally not do this of course but can image this accidentally happening to a less experienced developer.